# Meaing of `schedule_interval=None` and `start_date=airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(n)` in an Airflow DAG?

Tags: airflow

I don't understand how to interpret the combination of `schedule_interval=None` and `start_date=airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(3)` in an Airflow DAG. If the `schedule_interval` was `'@daily'`, then (I think) the following DAG would wait for the start of the next day, and then run three times once a day, backfilling the `days_ago(3)`. I do know that because `schedule_interval=None`, it will have to be manually started, but I don't understand the behavior beyond that. What is the point of the `days_ago(3)`?

```py
dag = DAG(
    dag_id="chapter9_aws_handwritten_digit_classifier",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(3),
)
```

The example is from https://github.com/BasPH/data-pipelines-with-apache-airflow/blob/master/chapter07/digit_classifier/dags/chapter9_digit_classifier.py

Comment: Dont use dynamic values in start_date. Its bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion is understandable. This is also confusing for the Airflow scheduler which is why using dynamic values for start_date considered a bad practice. To quote from the [Airflow FAQ](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date):

> We recommend against using dynamic values as start_date

The reason for this is because Airflow calculates DAG scheduling using `start_date` as base and `schedule_interval` as period. When reaching the end of the period the DAG is triggered. However when the `start_date` is dynamic there is a risk that the period will never end because the base always "moving".

To ease your confusion just change the start_date to some static value and then it will make sense to you.

Noting also that the guide that you referred to was written before [AIP-39 Richer scheduler_interval](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-39+Richer+scheduler_interval) was implemented. Starting Airflow 2.2.0 it's much easier to schedule DAGs. You can read about `Timetables` in the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/timetable.html).